Need guidance on solving a Failed to Fetch error using Stripe's Payment API
I am building out a simple web app (using React, Express, and Stripe's API). When trying to go to the external Stripe Payments page, I get a Failed to Fetch error. I'm not sure what's going wrong, as everything besides this seems to be working just fine.
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at checkout (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:479:11)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22436:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22480:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22537:35)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22551:29)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26694:7)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26720:11)
    at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26731:9)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26740:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26900:16

Here is my Navbar.js page:
import {Button, Container, Navbar, Modal} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { CartContext } from "../CartContext";
import CartProduct from './CartProduct';

function NavbarComponent() {
    const cart = useContext(CartContext);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false); // so ShoppingCart is not displaying on startup
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const checkout = async () => {
        await fetch('http://localhost:4000/checkout', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({items: cart.items})
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).then((response) => {
            if(response.url) {
                window.location.assign(response.url); // Forwarding user to Stripe
            }
        });
    }

    const productsCount = cart.items.reduce((sum, product) => sum + product.quantity, 0);

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar expand="sm">
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">Test</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle />
                <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
                    <Button onClick={handleShow}>Cart ({productsCount} Items)</Button>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Shopping Cart</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    {productsCount > 0 ?
                        <>
                            <p>Items in your cart:</p>
                            {cart.items.map( (currentProduct, idx) => (
                                <CartProduct key={idx} id={currentProduct.id} quantity={currentProduct.quantity}></CartProduct>
                            ))}

                            <h1>Total: {cart.getTotalCost().toFixed(2)}</h1>

                            <Button variant="success" onClick={checkout}>
                                Purchase items!
                            </Button>
                        </>
                    :
                        <h1>There are no items in your cart!</h1>
                    }
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
}

export default NavbarComponent;

Here is my server.js page as well:
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const stripe = require('stripe')('');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/checkout", async (req, res) => {
 
    console.log(req.body);
    const items = req.body.items;
    let lineItems = [];
    items.forEach((item)=> {
        lineItems.push(
            {
                price: item.id,
                quantity: item.quantity
            }
        )
    });

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: lineItems,
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: "http://localhost:3000/success",
        cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
    });

    res.send(JSON.stringify({
        url: session.url
    }));
});

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Listening on port 4000"));

Does this have something to do with my localhosts/connections? Like I mentioned, everything seems to be working in terms of the front-end/UI just fine.

Can you hit your /checkout endpoint with a tool like Postman or cURL? Does that work? Also, you are trying to hit http://localhost:4000/checkout. Is 4000 the right port?

@codename_duchess - To be honest, I'm not sure if it's the right port I should be using. I was following along with some documentation/tutorials regarding the API side of things, everything else has been on 3000. Do you have a recommendation for how to go about it? It doesn't look like the :4000/checkout port or anything is responding.

Stripe's documentation doesn't use a fetch, but a form POST https://docs.stripe.com/checkout/quickstart followed by a serverside redirect. Would that be a solution for you?

You are running the server handling Stripe requests on port 4000 and client side on port 3000. Check that your express server is running and take a look at its logs and make a manual request to the endpoint (http://localhost:4000/checkout) and check the response.
